# Funcionalidad de BitmapFactory

Tags: android, api, bitmap

Llevo un rato navegando por la `API` de android intentando entender la funcion de `BitmapFactory`.

¿En que momentos se supone que debo usar `BitmapFactory`, y por qué?

Comment: Quizá esto pueda ayudarte un poco https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase **[BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html)** crea objetos de mapa de bits a partir de diversas fuentes que pueden ser **archivos, streams, o  byte-arrays**. Se sugiere su uso cuando cargas imagenes desde la sdcard o disco.

Un ejemplo, crear un objeto mapa de bits a partir de una imagen almacenada en la sdcard y la cual agregamos a un ImageView:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mi_imagen);
//Convierte a mapa de bits
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/mi_imagen.png");
//Carga imagen en imageView obtenida a partir de un recurso.
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
```